# Get alert and get text in the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to get alert from the main big circle alone. The alert should not come from the small circles. 
How to get alert from the big circle alone? and Text for small circle should be in the bottom the each circle. For me its showing in the top right corner of the circles. Can anyone help me to solve this thing?
Thanks in advance

```js
var noop = function() {
  return this;
};

function UserCanceledError() {
  this.name = 'UserCanceledError';
  this.message = 'User canceled dialog';
}
UserCanceledError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);

function Dialog() {
  this.setCallbacks(noop, noop);
}
Dialog.prototype.setCallbacks = function(okCallback, cancelCallback) {
  this._okCallback     = okCallback;
  return this;
};
Dialog.prototype.waitForUser = function() {
  var _this = this;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    _this.setCallbacks(resolve, reject);
  });
};

Dialog.prototype.show = noop;
Dialog.prototype.hide = noop;

function PromptDialog() {
  Dialog.call(this);
  this.el           = document.getElementById('dialog');
  this.messageEl    = this.el.querySelector('.message');
  this.okButton     = this.el.querySelector('button.ok');
  this.attachDomEvents();
}
PromptDialog.prototype = Object.create(Dialog.prototype);
PromptDialog.prototype.attachDomEvents = function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.okButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    _this.hide();
    console.log('Ok clicked!!');
  });
  
};
PromptDialog.prototype.show = function(message) {
  this.messageEl.innerHTML = '' + message;
  this.el.className = '';
  return this;
};
PromptDialog.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.el.className = 'hidden';
  return this;
};


var prompt = new PromptDialog();

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});

const drawBall = (ball, ctx) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

const updatePos = (ball, containerR) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}

function makeArea(domid, radius, ballsNumber) {
  const ctx = document.getElementById(domid).getContext("2d");
  const containerR = radius;
  const size = radius * 2
  ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  
  let balls = [];
  for(var i=0 ; i<ballsNumber ; ++i) {
    const r = Math.random()*radius*0.5;
    const t = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
    balls.push(getBall(radius + Math.cos(t)*r, radius + Math.sin(t)*r, 0.1, 0.1, 5, "Green"));
  }
  
  return {
    ctx: ctx,
    radius: radius,
    balls: balls
  }
}

const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));

const areas = [
  makeArea("Canvas", 150, 10, true),
  makeArea("Canvas1", 80, 4, false),
  makeArea("Canvas2", 80, 4, false),
  makeArea("Canvas3", 80, 4, false),
  makeArea("Canvas4", 80, 4, false)
];

function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  mydiv.textContent =" ";
  areas.forEach((area) =>{
    const ctx = area.ctx;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    area.balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
      a.collider = undefined;

      area.balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
        if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
        if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
      });

      if (a.collider) { // If ball has a collider:
       //mydiv.textContent = ("Alert");
       //beep();
       prompt.show('ALERT!!!!! Not Maintaining Distance')
        .waitForUser()
        .then(function(name) {
          output.innerHTML = '' + name;
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
          console.log('Unknown error', e);
        })
        .finally(function() {
          prompt.hide();
        });

        //console.log(`${a.color[0]} → ← ${a.collider.color[0]}`);
      }
      updatePos(a, area.radius);
      drawBall(a, ctx);
    });
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}

engine();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;

}
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.Row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 8%;
  float: right;
}

#Canvas1, #Canvas2, #Canvas3, #Canvas4 {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 0px #000;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
    <div>
        <canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <canvas id="Canvas1"></canvas>
              <span> xyz</span>
            <canvas id="Canvas2"></canvas>
             <span> xyz1</span>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="row">
            <canvas id="Canvas3"></canvas>
            <span> xyz2</span>
            <canvas id="Canvas4"></canvas>
            <span>xyz3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="dialog" class="hidden">
  <div class="message"></div>
  <div>
    <button class="ok">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your second question:

The `<span>s` are just children of .row, like the canvas is. You could "group" them with the canvas and make their position absolute:

```css
/* important stuff: */
.group {
  position: relative;
}
.group span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* only for testing: */
#canvas1 { 
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
.row {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="group">
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <span>xyz</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

About the alert from the big circle:

If you're extending your forEach on all areas with a variable for the index ...

```
areas.forEach((area, areaindex) => {
```

... you could check for index zero later:

```
if (a.collider && areaindex == 0)
```

Comment: Thank for your support...i got the alert thing done..but how to separate the 2 circles which is touching other? i added span class also but now it touching the right side circles